# C++ Array in a prime number search

Tags: c++, arrays

So I was trying to answer a question on Project Euler (The question was: Find the 10,001 prime number), and ran into a problem that I don't know why it is happening. When I run the following C++ code,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int arr[10001]={2}, term=1, i, num=3;
     while(term!=10001)
    {
        for(i=0; i<term; i++)
        {
            if(num%arr[i]==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i==term){
            arr[term]=num;
            cout<< arr[term]<< " is prime"<< endl;
            term++;
        }
        num++;
    }
    cout<< arr[term]<< endl;
}
```

I always get `cout<< arr[term]<< endl;` printing out whatever `n++;`(next number in this case but if I were to change that to `n=856`then it would print out that number). I dont understand why that array term would change since I thought it would only change when `arr[term]=num;`is executed

Comment: where is the 'n' in your code ? Do you mean 'num' ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has *[undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)* because you are accessing the array outside of its bounds.

When the loop breaks, the value of `term` is `10001`, which is the 10002nd element of the array `arr` whereas your array memory allocated only for `10001` elements.

To print the last element of the array, do:

```
cout<< arr[term - 1]<< endl;
```

Comment: Why does it output the last iteration of num++; though

Comment: Is that just a default if when I'm trying to go out of the bounds of the array

Comment: I don't understand your first comment. When you go out of bounds, *anything* can happen and there's no default. Print the value of `term` inside the loop and you'll see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I mean why would it print the last iteration of num++; before it breaks out of while loop (it always prints out 10,001 prime number +1

Comment: If you still don't understand my question its fine I'll fool around with the code more and hopefully figure it out

Answer (score 1):

In every iteration, you execute

```
arr[term]=num;
cout<< arr[term]<< " is prime"<< endl;
term++;
```

So when the `while` ends, `term` is one more that the one you used for the last assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to output the `arr[term-1]` instead of `arr[term]` because `term` is incremented at the end of the assignment to the `arr[]`, hence the `term` variable is 1 more `10001`.

Edited code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int arr[10002]={2}, term=1, i, num=3;
     while(term!=10001)
    {
        for(i=0; i<term; i++)
        {
            if(num%arr[i]==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i==term){
            arr[term]=num;
            cout<< arr[term]<< " is prime"<< endl;
            term++;
        }
        num++;
    }
    cout<< arr[term-1]<< endl;
  //Your 'term' variable actually is term + 1, hence, you have
  //to print the element at 'term - 1'.
}
```